# Outlook VBA Move Single Email To Numerous Folders

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to move email from one existing folder to one or more subfolders.

Simple example: An email arrives from John Doe. Move it to a MMYY  subfolder (that may not exist) under folder named Doe, John (that may not exist).   If the email is marked high importance, put a copy of the email in a 2nd subfolder named "HighImportance". Lastly if the email is identified as a HighVolumeEmailer from an SQL query, move to a 3rd subfolder named "HighVolumeEmailer".

The VBA moves an email to a MMYY folder, but it could potentially save copies of the same email to two other folders. A total of three.

Here is my code that does not work:

```
Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.folders(sSenderName)

If objDestFolder Is Nothing Then
    Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.folders.Add(sSenderName)
End If

Set objNewFolder = objDestFolder.folders(sMonthandYearOfEMail)

If objNewFolder Is Nothing Then
    Set objNewFolder = objDestFolder.folders.Add(sMonthandYearOfEMail)
End If

objVariant.Move objNewFolder
'count the # of items moved
lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1

'''''if marked high importance put copy in high importance folder
If sEMailImportance = "High" Then

    '''''Set myCopiedItem = objVariant.Copy

    ''''Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.folders(sSenderName)

    Set objHighImportanceFolder = objNamespace.folders(sSenderName).folders(sMonthandYearOfEMail).folders("MarkedHighImportance")

    '''''Set objHighImportanceFolder = objDestFolder.folders("MarkedHighImportance")

    If objHighImportanceFolder Is Nothing Then
        Set objHighImportanceFolder = objNamespace.folders(sSenderName).folders(sMonthandYearOfEMail).Add(sMarkedHighImportance)
    End If

    objVariant.UnRead = True
    Set copy = objVariant.copy
    copy.Move.objHighImportanceFolder
    objVariant.UnRead = True

End If

''''''Now going to look for high volume calls
sEMailSubject = objVariant.Subject

blnHighVMVolume = False
LookingForThisTelephoneNumberInHighVolume = Mid(sEMailSubject, 24, 10)
g = 0

For g = LBound(vArray, 2) To UBound(vArray, 2)

    'This is where the code will determine if the telephone number is in
    'the high call volume population

    If vArray(0, g) = LookingForThisTelephoneNumberInHighVolume Then

        blnHighVMVolume = True
        NumberOfHighVolumeVMs = vArray(1, g)

    End If

Next g

If blnHighVMVolume = True Then
    ''''''Set myCopiedItem = objVariant.Copy
    Set objHighVolumeFolder = objNamespace.folders(sSenderName).folders(sMonthandYearOfEMail).folders(sHighVolumeCaller)

    If objHighVolumeFolder Is Nothing Then
        Set objHighVolumeFolder = objNamespace.folders(sSenderName).folders(sMonthandYearOfEMail).Add(sHighVolumeCaller)
    End If

    objVariant.UnRead = True
    Set copy = objVariant.copy
    copy.Move.objHighVolumeFolder
    objVariant.UnRead = True

End If
```

Comment: What line of code doesn't work?  What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Whatever else could be wrong replace Set copy = objVariant.copy with something like Set objcopy = objVariant.copy

Answer (score 0):

> The VBA moves an email to a MMYY folder, but it could potentially save copies of the same email to two other folders. A total of three.

It seems you need to use the [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868420(v=office.15).aspx) method of Outlook items to make three copies and then [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx) them to these folders. For example:

```
Set myCopiedItem = myItem.Copy  
myCopiedItem.Move myNewFolder
```

Anyway, in your code I have noticed the following lines:

```
 Set copy = objVariant.copy
 copy.Move.objHighImportanceFolder
```

It looks like you need to correct the second line of code: objHighImportanceFolder is not a property or method, it is an argument passed to the function. Should look like:

```
 Set copy = objVariant.copy
 copy.Move objHighImportanceFolder
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!  That fixed the move copy problem but I still have a problem with trying to set the subfolder(s).  Can you or someone tell me how to set the folders to move the emails to?  I need to move the email to a Folder Named HighImportanceEmails.  This HighImportanceEmails subfolder is a under a series of other folders.  Here is the folder structure - Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.folders(sSenderName)
                    Set objHighImportanceFolder = objDestFolder.folders(sMonthandYearOfEMail).folders("MarkedHighImportance")   Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You explained how to move/copy but that is only 1/2 my problem. I am trying to figure out how to set the subfolders to move copies to.  Setting the subfolder is what I don't know how to do. How can I code to save the copy to a folder that is located here -  sSenderName/MMYY/HighImportanceFolder.    I can move emails to sSenderName/MMYY using  the existing code but I can't move the copy of the email to the 3rd folder.   Can you help explain how to Set the folder to the 3rd folder down?